# Want to display second last value and prior to second last value in RDLC report

Tags: sql, rdlc

I m using SQL Database and have one table in which i want to display second last value and prior to second last value
like personal value ( 1,2,3,4,5,6...10) want to display value8 and 9 in RDLC report
how i will do that please let me know
I m using Previous function but it returns blank

```
SELECT AtcDetails.BuyerStyle, AtcDetails.Quantity, AtcDetails.FOB,
  AtcDetails.OurStyle, AtcMaster.AtcNum, StyleCostingDetails.Consumption,
  StyleCostingDetails.PriceperDozen, StyleCostingDetails.Rate,
  StyleCostingMaster.CreatedDate, StyleCostingMaster.CostingCount 
FROM AtcMaster 
CROSS JOIN StyleCostingMaster 
INNER JOIN StyleCostingDetails ON StyleCostingMaster.Costing_PK = StyleCostingDetails.Costing_PK 
INNER JOIN AtcDetails ON StyleCostingMaster.OurStyleID = AtcDetails.OurStyleID
```

Comment: Please add SQL code which you have tried at your end.

Comment: SELECT        AtcDetails.BuyerStyle, AtcDetails.Quantity, AtcDetails.FOB, AtcDetails.OurStyle, AtcMaster.AtcNum, StyleCostingDetails.Consumption, StyleCostingDetails.PriceperDozen, StyleCostingDetails.Rate,                     StyleCostingMaster.CreatedDate, StyleCostingMaster.CostingCount
FROM            AtcMaster CROSS JOIN
                         StyleCostingMaster INNER JOIN
                         StyleCostingDetails ON StyleCostingMaster.Costing_PK = StyleCostingDetails.Costing_PK INNER JOIN
                         AtcDetails ON StyleCostingMaster.OurStyleID = AtcDetails.OurStyleID

Comment: I m getting FOB values but want to display sencond last value